# ArcObjects Mobile SDK, how do you get length/distance of a polyline

Tags: mobile, sdk, polyline, arcobjects

I programmatically select a polyline using an attribute query statement and returning the geometry of it.  Then I use that to zoom-in to the area.
I'm needing to the length of the polyline in order to zoom-in to the area based on the length.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the geometry of the polyline:

```
        '
        ' --- Get the length of the polyline
        '
        Dim mPolyline As Polyline
        Dim mPolylineLength As Double
        '
        mPolyline = gGeometry
        mPolylineLength = mPolyline.GetLength()
```